# Send other data from UITableView to ViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I have a Decodable Proto which holds data.

The Name is displayed on a label in the UITableViewCell but the message isn't but needs to be transferred with the Name.

A message gets displayed, but it`s the one of the previous cell. If I close the DetailView and click the cell again, the right message is displayed.

```
struct Response: Decodable {
                    let array: [Content]

                    struct Content: Decodable {

                        let Name: String
                        let Message: String
                    }
                }

    var responseDec: Response?
```

That's the didSelectRow and prepare func

```
var username = ""
var message = ""

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

         let res = self.responseDec?.array[indexPath.row]

          index = indexPath.row

          username = res?.Name ?? "N/A"
          message = res?.Message ?? "N/A"

          let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? Cell

         performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToVC", sender: cell)

    }

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "goToVC" {

            let cell = sender as? Cell

            let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController


             vc.name = cell?.nameLabel.text ?? "N/A"
             vc.message = message

          }
}
```

Comment: `vc.name = cell?.nameLabel.text ?? "N/A` why isn't this `vc.name username`? Also, do you write somewhere else` message = `?

Comment: @Larme no, message isn't declared anywhere else

Comment: in the performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToVC", sender: res) // you shouldn't grab the cell here, try sending the data instead (res)

Comment: The line `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? Cell` in your `tableView(didSelect:)` makes no sense. Don't do that. You should be fetching your data from your model, not creating a cell and passing that cell as a sender. That's really bad coding.

Comment: @DuncanC So put the code in the model and than fetch the message with indexPath.row as a global variable?

Comment: "put the code in the model"? No. Write code in your data source that fetches the data from the model. When the user taps a cell, you should save the IndexPath of that cell, and then in `prepare(for:sender:)` use the saved `IndexPath` to fetch the data from the model and pass it to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try to grab the data for selected index path by creating a global variable. Try this**

```
 var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     selectedIndexPath = indexPath
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToVC", sender: self)

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goToVC" {

      if let indexpath = selectedIndexPath, let vc = segue.destination as? ViewController{
           let res = self.responseDec?.array[indexpath.row]
           vc.name = res?.Name ?? "N/A"
           vc.message = res?.Message ?? "N/A"

      }}}
```

Comment: That also didn't help. Its still the previous message, which gets displayed

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use present or push to show your view controller. And check your data with a break point.

***Or if you wanna keep use segue;***

- Keep segue identifier as a constant
- Use guard let casting a cell
- Create a struct that includes name and message
- Give the model to performSegue as the sender and catch it with guard let in the prepare function